# tikz-cd equivalent to the xy-pic command \ar@{-}

Tags: xy-pic, tikz-cd

How do I make the diagram

`X - Y -> Z`

with tikz-cd?

With xy-pic, I would enter

`\xymatrix{ X \ar@{-}[r] & Y \ar[r] & Z }`

I tried

`\begin{tikzcd} X \ar[no head]{r} & Y \ar{r} & Z \end{tikzcd}`

but it didn't work.

Note that

`\begin{tikzcd} X \ar[two heads]{r} & Y \ar{r} & Z \end{tikzcd}`

produces

`X ->> Y -> Z`

"as it should".

In other words:

What is the tikz-cd equivalent to the xy-pic command `\ar@{-}`?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

**EDIT.** Peter Jansson kindly asked me to provide a Minimal Working Example (MWE). So here is what works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
$$
\xymatrix{ X \ar@{-}[r] & Y\ar[r] & Z}
$$
$$
\begin{tikzcd} 
X \ar[two heads]{r} & Y \ar{r} & Z 
\end{tikzcd}
$$
\end{document}
```

Here is what doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
$$
\begin{tikzcd} 
X \ar[no head]{r} & Y \ar{r} & Z 
\end{tikzcd}
$$
\end{document}
```

I get the error message

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: 
I do not know the key '/tikz/no head' 
and I am going to ignore it. 
Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

This doesn't surprise me because I just tried to guess at a possible command. But I hope that there is a simple way to do this.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/19384) that clearly shows your problem. This should start with \documentclass and end with \end{document}.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Dear @ClaudioFiandrino: Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Dear @PeterJansson: Thanks for your suggestion. I made an edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the optional argument to `\ar` that allows for specifying the arrow's shape, shift and whatnot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd} 
X \ar[-]{r} & Y \ar{r} & Z 
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

Never use `$$` in LaTeX.

[image]

Comment: Dear egreg: Thanks a lot! How did you figure that out? Is there a list of all the possible optional arguments you can use in this situation?

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard The [official documentation](http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf).