# Parallel arrows without heads

Tags: tikz-cd

The official tikz-cd is available [here](http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf).

On page 3, one reads:

> The following list shows all available arrows.

I tried all items in the list, and got error messages for the three items: `dash`, `equal`, and `mapsfrom`.

All the other items worked perfectly.

As pointed out by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) in his answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96439/tikz-cd-equivalent-to-the-xy-pic-command-ar), one can use `[-]` instead of `[dash]`.

I tried to use `[=]` instead of `[equal]`, but it didn't work.

I got a not very good-looking `mapsfrom` using `[<-|]`.

Of course I'd be delighted to have an explanation, but, above all, I'd like to find a way of obtaining the `equal` and `mapsfrom` arrows (mainly the `equal` one).

Here is a Minimal Working Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
X \ar[equal]{r} & Y
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I suspect you have an outdated `tikz-cd` package, because with `[equal]` and `[mapsfrom]` I get the expected result. In the log file I have `tikz-cd 2012/12/30 v0.3c`

Comment: Dear @egreg: I think you're right: in my log file I have `tikz-cd 2012/03/18 v0.2b`. I'll download the current version, but this may take a while because I have a slow connection. I'll let you know. Thank you very much for your edit and your comment (which, I'm pretty sure, is an answer).

Comment: Dear @egreg: I haven't been able so far to update the package, but I don't have the slightest doubt about the correctness of what you say. If you upgrade your comment to an answer, I'll be delighted to upvote and accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I get (`tikz-cd` version 0.3c, `tikz` version 2.10) from

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
X \ar[equal]{r} & Y \ar[mapsfrom]{r} & Z
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One other thing that may be wrong is your viewer.

The = arrow was not displaying for me in TeXstudio, but when I increased the magnification it was visible and looked fine.   It was also visible in the PDF output.  Assuming you are not getting build errors, this may be what is happening.