# Removing arrow tips in TikZCD

Tags: tikz-cd

I love the TikZcd syntax to draw diagrams, and I want to use it to draw diagrams of field extensions ; this involves drawing arrows *without tips*. The only command I know to draw lines in tikzcd environments is `\ar` (or `\arrow` if I write it out), and I don't know how to adjust the \ar command so that it just draws straight lines from point `A` to point `B` (recall it is used in the following way : `\ar[options]{rd}[options]{$\phi$}` to render an arrow which goes right-down and put the symbol `$\phi$` next to the arrow.

I tried simply putting TikZ commands, but they seem to have no effect (even though it compiles for most of the commands I've tried).

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I always forget how to render this...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Section 1.2 of [`tikz-cd`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz-cd) documentation details this; in particular, it sounds like you might want `dash`

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \arrow[dash]{r} & B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Following the comments, you can apply `dash` to every arrow for the current environment using

```
\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={dash}]
  A \arrow{r} & B
\end{tikzcd}
```

Comment: Wow, how did I go through the whole document without seeing this. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know if I can make the [dash] option applied to the whole environment? Otherwise I have to type \ar[dash] all the time.

Comment: For some reason, this code is not working : 

    \begin{tikzcd}
 K \arrow[dash]{d} \\
 F
    \end{tikzcd}. I get the error "Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/dash' and I am going to i
gnore it. Perhaps you misspelled it."

Comment: Added : lucky me, only the `dash` option seems to fail, the (most of) other arrow tips in section 1.2 run just fine.

Comment: This answer helped me. Problem solved! http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100998/parallel-arrows-without-heads

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva see my update about the whole environment

Comment: @cmhughes instead of `dash` one can also simply use `-`, as in `\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={-}]
  A \arrow{r} & B
\end{tikzcd}`
 (apparently the `dash` option is not available for the OP's version of the package, but I guess `-` will be.)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Apparently the version of tikz-cd the arxiv uses doesn't accept `dash`, but does accept `-`, so thanks!  This comment gave me an easy fix for making my file arxiv-compatible.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Thanks for pointing out the solution on how to replace dash to make things arxiv compatible. I was fighting for several hours with several problems of the outdated and buggy arxiv version of tikz-cd. In case someone else gets faced with another problem which took me quite some time to resolve it: The arxiv version of tikz-cd produces bizarre error messages when the first line of a tikzcd environment starts with a &. The solution finally was to put a {} before &.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the above: If you want more flexibility than the "dash" type arrow there is also the "no head" command which removes the head from any type of arrow.